# When switching off the engine, do the cam and crank shafts always come to rest in an initial state?

Tags: engine-theory, camshaft, crankshaft, piston, valve-timing

Is it the case, when the engine comes to a halt, that the cylinder/piston/valve phases always finish up in the same starting or initial position relative to each other?

Comment: Are you asking if the engine always stops at the same place? (IE: cylinder 1 piston always stops at top dead center)

Comment: Yes, that's another way of asking the question.

Answer (score 3):

No. An engine stops where it stops because it is random when you turn the ignition off, and therefore there is no set place for it to end up at.

Comment: Right, okay. And presumably the phases remain sync'ed, across starting and stopping the engine. Is that right?

Comment: What do you mean by "phases"?

Comment: They are all connected mechanically, so of course they stay in-sync, in-phase, or whatever you want to call it.  Unless something like a timing belt/chain/gear breaks, but that's pathological.

Comment: Ok, Mike65535 answered the question.

Comment: in fact the reason it is called a timing belt is that it keeps the timing in sync.